# error booting ubuntu on chromebook:_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

Tags: 12.04, kernel, chromebook

Here is the whole error report. I already ran into trouble once and had to reinstall the Ubuntu croot.

```
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...

_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.8.11 #1 SMP Tue Aug 2 21:07:18 PDT 2016 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure  console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 2506752 verity payload=PARTUUID=099cc490-7c10-d544-8e14-62ec05a5c497/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=099cc490-7c10-d544-8e14-62ec05a5c497/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=2506752 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=25db33872914fd7b5c8ca0df301c145a839f948b salt= e3821ceded498fdebc583fc952517083a5e5798641d92e6a21519321dbef9a49" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=099cc490-7c10-d544-8e14-62ec05a5c497 add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic iTCO_vendor_support.vendorsupport=3  
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:01PM
xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.17 (For technical support please see ) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
    Before reporting problems, check 
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log", Time: Wed Aug 24 23:56:55 2016
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"

Fatal server error:
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)


Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 

Please also check the log file at "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log" for additional information.

ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
/usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
chronos@localhost / $ sudo startunity
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...

_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.8.11 #1 SMP Tue Aug 2 21:07:18 PDT 2016 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure  console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 2506752 verity payload=PARTUUID=099cc490-7c10-d544-8e14-62ec05a5c497/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=099cc490-7c10-d544-8e14-62ec05a5c497/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=2506752 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=25db33872914fd7b5c8ca0df301c145a839f948b salt=e3821ceded498fdebc583fc952517083a5e5798641d92e6a21519321dbef9a49" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=099cc490-7c10-d544-8e14-62ec05a5c497 add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic iTCO_vendor_support.vendorsupport=3  
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:01PM
xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.17 (For technical support please see ) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
    Before reporting problems, check 
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log", Time: Thu Aug 25 00:00:51 2016
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"

Fatal server error:
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)


Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
at 
for help. 
Please also check the log file at "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log" for additional information.

 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
/usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
```

Comment: Did you sudo first? This *MAY* help:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/09/ubuntu-tips-how-to-login-using-su-command-su-gives-authentication-failure-error-message/

Comment: Do you have other OS's installed with crouton on that machine? I had the same problem and I think that's where it's coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this problem myself after updating ubuntu but i got it wokring by updating my chroot

```
sudo sh -e ~/Downloads/crouton -n (chroot name) -u
```

and if you dont know your chroot's name just do

```
ls /usr/local/chroots
```

and your chroots name will be there

;) i will monitor this thread if anyone else needs help

PS: if you try updating ubuntu to 14.04 (dont upgrade to 16.04 it will not work) you must run the first command the first time you boot into the upgraded version